# Android Tabbed Application

Tags: android

I tried to implement an application where you have 2 tabs in the top.

Each of this tabs shows a `ListView`, the only difference is that this `ListView` is filled with different content from an `ArrayList`.

I tried several steps to fulfil this task, but most stuff on the web is deprecated. Any advise which way would be the actual state of the art?

As I said: I managed to find a lot of tutorials for this task, but again, most of them are from 2012 or something and Android Studio marks them as deprecated.

Would be nice, to have some advices!

EDIT: 
What I tried to implement:

A `TabHost`solution:

```
  TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
                    TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
                    TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab");
                    TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third tab");


                    tab1.setIndicator("Tab1");
                    tab1.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab1Activity.class));

                    tab2.setIndicator("Tab2");
                    tab2.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab2Activity.class));
                    tabHost.addTab(tab1);
                    tabHost.addTab(tab2);
```

Also I tried to apply tabs to the `ActionBar` like this. The problem was that the line `ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar` returned `null`:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                       .setText(R.string.artist)
                       .setTabListener(new TabListener<ArtistFragment>(
                               this, "artist", ArtistFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

And several other attemps, which I deleted already.

Comment: can you post a piece of  code what you tried so far.

Comment: hello gangulian, i added the attempts to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I use  [this tutorials](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) and they work perfectly fine. Use fragments to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Google has posted a sample of a the layout I think you are looking for. Take a look at it:

https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html

Those source codes are available to Download

Edit: here you got the full project view https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/project.html